# Validating email that has @something.co.uk

Tags: forms, validation, email

I have the following regex options:

```
let emailValid = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/"
    emailValid = "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$"
    emailValid = `/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`
    emailValid =  "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/"
```

And none are able to consistently reject `@somethingcouk` while accepting `@something.co.uk`

The advice given here is just plain wrong https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

It suggests `/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/` which, according to them, should accept `mysite@you.me.net`, but in my case it does not accept `something@yahoo.co.uk`.

I'd like not to spend 3 days learning the regex to do this, when various tutorials and stack overflow answers are already given. What am I doing wrong here?

Does inputting these as a variable, without using `match()`, as some places suggest, affect the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The options you list are all **strings**.

While there are cases where you can convert a string to a regular expression, your approach is breaking all the escape characters (because a `\` starts an escape sequence in both strings and regular expressions.

Use a regular expression literal instead:

```
const emailValid = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
```

Possibly not that one though because top-level domain names are no longer restricted to 2 or 3 characters. There's a reason that the email address validation browsers apply to `input type=email` generally isn't any more complex than "Contains an `@` sign".

Answer (score 0):

I have made this long time ago and this also accept email address for ip domain like something@112.22.12.1

```
function checkEmailPattern(str) {
    const pattern = /^([^\.\_\-\@])+([^\.\@\_\-])*((([^\d\@]){0,1})[a-z0-9]{2,}){0,1}((@([a-zA-Z]{2,})+(\.([a-z]{2,})){1,2}|@(\d{3}.){1,3})|(@([0-9]{1,3})+(\.([0-9]{1,3})){3}))$/;

    return pattern.test(str.toLowerCase());
}

let value1 = 'something@yahoo.co.uk';

console.log(checkEmailPattern(value1)); // true
```

[image: Test List From controlChecker.js]